# lists:map() on mnesia:table_info(table, attributes)

Tags: list, erlang, records, mnesia

I want to do operation on Mnesia table on each attribute of the table.

```
Record = #table{attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4},
```

`mnesia:table_info(Table, attributes)` gives a list of attributes which are atoms i.e `[attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4]`

```
lists:map(fun(X) -> Record#table.X end, mnesia:table_info(Table, attributes))
```

I'm expecting the above function to give list of values. 
But, i'm getting error

```
"  * 1: syntax error before: X  "
```

I have already defined the table structure using the shell command
`-rd(table, {})` and also have used `-rr(module)` to read the record structure

What is wrong in the above code??
Any, alternative to process the table attributes using lists module??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You cannot refer to record items by name in runtime. It's one of record drawbacks.*

In runtime records are just tuples with the first element being the name of record, so

```
#table{attr1 = 1, attr2 = 2, attr3 = 3, attr4 = 4} =:= {table, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

As you can see, all naming information is lost.

But all your function looks a bit useless. If you want to get all values, you can use record itself.